# Please give any feedback, advice or any help on very simple JAVA program assignment

Tags: java

i was able to get most of it done but i have been stuck what to write next

ASSIGNMENT - create a program that will print 
Expected output :

"Enter first integer: 1729

Enter second integer: 845

first + second = 2574

first - second = 844

first / second = 2

first * second = 1461005

MY code :

````
import java.util.scanner;

public class program_2_1
{
public static void main(string[]args) 
{

int first_int = 0;
int second_int = 0;

scanner keyboard = new Scanner(system.in);

System.out.print("Enter first integer");
first_int = keyboard.nextint();

System.out.printin("second integer");
second_int = keyboard.nextint();

System.out.printin("first + second = " + (first_int + second_int));

}
} ```
````

Comment: I think you mean `println` not `printin`

Comment: `java.util.Scanner` and `Scanner` not `scanner`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Java programming!

You have some syntax errors in your code:

- The correct header for a main method has a capital S for String and a space between `String[]` and `args`. String[] is the data type (i.e. an array of strings) and args is the parameter name.
- Conventional Java styling says that braces should go at the end of the line, not on the next line. If you are using a code editor like Eclipse, you can press `Ctrl+Shift+F` to have your code formatted correctly.
- Java also has a camelCase standard for variable names. Opt for `firstInt` and `secondInt` as opposed to using underscores.
- The first letter of class names in Java should be capitalized. When you are creating a `Scanner`, you are creating an object that is of type Scanner. In other words, you are instantiating the Scanner class. Scanner is the name of a class in the Java library, so its first letter should be capitalized.
- On the same note, the first letter of `System` should also be capitalized. Make sure to do the same in the `import` statement at the top of your code.
- Java does not recognize the function `nextint()` because it is strictly case-sensitive. It only recognized `nextInt()` where the I is capitalized, following camelCase standard Java naming conventions for methods.
- As mentioned by @ScaryWombat, printin() is not a method built into the Java library. You may have intended to use println() with an l which makes the following print statements display on the next line.

To calculate the difference, product and quotient of the inputted integers, you can follow the format you used for addition.

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int firstInt = 0;
        int secondInt = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter first integer");
        firstInt = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("second integer");
        secondInt = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("first + second = " + (firstInt + secondInt));

        System.out.println("first - second = " + (firstInt - secondInt));

        System.out.println("first / second = " + (firstInt / secondInt));

        System.out.println("first * second = " + (firstInt * secondInt));

    }
}
```

Overall, good job collecting user input, concatenating strings and printing them to the console!

Good luck on your Java programming journey!